# Cannot get value in class list

Tags: c#, list, class

I've got 1 class and 2 form

Main form will load the product in the list from database

```
for (int i = 1; i < TileProduct.Length; i++)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    conn.ConnectionString = @"source;" + "integrated security=true";
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    string query = "Select Product_Name, Price, Description, Image from Product where Product_ID = @id ";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i);
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                fill.FillProduct.Add(new product
                {
                    Name = reader.GetString(0),
                    Price = reader.GetDecimal(1),
                    Description = reader.GetString(2),
                    Image = reader.GetString(3)
                });
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    string id = Convert.ToString(i);

        var Tile = new PictureBox(); 
        TileProduct[i] = Tile;
        Tile.Text = id;
    Tile.Click += (s, e) => {
            item ShowPro = new item((Convert.ToInt32(Tile.Text)-1));
            ShowPro.StyleManager = metroStyleManager;
            ShowPro.metroStyleManager1.Style = metroStyleManager.Style;
            ShowPro.metroStyleManager1.Theme = metroStyleManager.Theme;
            ShowPro.ShowDialog();
        };
    Tile.Image = Image.FromFile(fill.FillProduct[Convert.ToInt32(Tile.Text) - 1].Image);
    Tile.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    Tile.Location = new Point((3 + add), 11);
        Tile.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        Shop.Controls.Add(TileProduct[i]);
    add = 120*i;
}
```

When product is click it will pass the product number in and a new form open containing this codes.

```
public item(int productNo)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    product fill = new product();
    sProduct = (fill.FillProduct[productNo].Name);

    this.Text = sProduct;

    sPrice = fill.FillProduct[productNo].Price;
    lblPrice.Text = "$" + sPrice;

    string Desc = fill.FillProduct[productNo].Description;
    lblDesc.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@Desc);

    string Img = fill.FillProduct[productNo].Image;
    picProduct.Image = Image.FromFile(Img);
}
```

The class that will be handling it will be

```
class product
{
    private List<product> Product = new List<product>();

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public List<product> FillProduct
    {
        set { Product = value; }
        get { return Product; }
    }
}
```

The problem is now that when I click on the product the list is empty. How do I fix it?

Comment: You should use a debugger to verify that at all stages your variables contain the expected values.

Comment: why and how do you think `public item(int productNo)` works? Because it doesnt work the way you think it works. Your main problem is the understanding of OOP => how does OO work, do i use a current object or a new object

Comment: Then is it possible to access the current object instead of using a new one?

Comment: sure it is, depending on what code you are allowed to change it can be very easy. If you are allowed to change your class `product` you just need to change `public List<product> FillProduct` to `public static List<product> FillProduct`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you call the item constructor

```
item ShowPro = new item((Convert.ToInt32(Tile.Text)-1));
```

And inside your constructor, you attempt to use a property list that is empty. Your `Product` list is property of your `item` class, meaning that is initialized for every object instance creation and belongs to that specific instance.

As a result, doing:

```
sProduct = fill.FillProduct[productNo].Name);
```

inside your constructor, nothing is previously inserted on the list, thus there is no `FillProduct[productNo]` value, therefore the `Name` indexing and other properties should result to a `NullReferenceException`.

Also, consider taking a look on [C# coding style conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx). Class names and Properties are considered to have a first-uppercase name, where local variables a lowercase, both following camelcase.

UPDATE: I just noticed that you use `fill.FillProduct.Add(....)` in your `while (reader.Read())` loop (I guess that fill is a property or a field, as I see no declaration of it in your code), and then inside your `item` constructor, you do:

```
product fill = new product();
```

Now the fill you initialize here has a different scope than the field declared at the top, and this one shadows the one above, meaning that the other fill object, while probably existing outside this scope, is not visible, as its variable reference is shadowed with another object.
Do not consider that those two are referencing to the same object, because they simply don't. Check out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) for more about the variable scoping.

Comment: There are products in the list. Is just that when the new form load there isn't any thjng inside.

Comment: No, there are not. Answer updated, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    fill.FillProduct.Add(new product
    {
        Name = reader.GetString(0),
        Price = reader.GetDecimal(1),
        Description = reader.GetString(2),
        Image = reader.GetString(3)
    });
}
```

you have this `fill` variable that seems to hold all of the products that are returned from the query. And as I read it, when the tile is clicked, the `item` code is in that new form. Are you actually passing the `fill` variable to the new form as well? Is `fill` a global? if so, its getting overwritten by `product fill = new product();` in the item method.

Comment: So how am I suppose to access the class without overwriting?

Comment: well it seems like in the first form, you have the `fill` variable that is chuck full of product data. But that variable never gets passed to the new form. You could either make the `fill` a static variable so it can be accessed anywhere, or you would have to pass `fill` into the constructor of the new form. Then you wouldn't do the `product fill = new product();` in item() as `fill` would already exist and hold all the information you need.

Comment: You should definitely study up on Object Oriented Programming. It looks like this is what you might be shooting for but you just aren't doing it correctly. For example, having a list<product> in class product doesn't make sense. You should have a class to maintain all of the parsed products and a class for a product. Also, its worth learning the styling conventions as pointed out by @nick-l.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer your problem in a way that you will learn what's your mistake is here are an boiled down example of what you do:

```
var A= new Car();
A.myFriends = fillCarWithFriends(); 

int seatNr = getSelectedFriendSeatNrFrom(A);

var B= new Car();
var myFriend = B.myFriends [seatNr];
```

which means you build 2 Cars (A and B). Then filled car A with lets say Friends and now you are trying to find a Friend in car B while he is in car A

---

To do what you are trying to do you need to change:

```
public List<product> FillProduct
{
    set { Product = value; }
    get { return Product; }
}
```

to

```
public static List<product> FillProduct
{
    set { Product = value; }
    get { return Product; }
}
```

now you are able to access `FillProduct` without needing an object
 by calling `product.FillProduct` in this case `product` is a type not an Object

---

Changed item method will look like :

```
public item(int productNo)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var selectedProduct = product.FillProduct[productNo];

    sProduct = (selectedProduct.Name);
    this.Text = sProduct;

    sPrice = selectedProduct.Price;
    lblPrice.Text = "$" + sPrice;

    string Desc = selectedProduct.Description;
    lblDesc.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@Desc);

    string Img = selectedProduct.Image;
    picProduct.Image = Image.FromFile(Img);
}
```

changed part where you fill your

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        product.FillProduct.Add(new product
        {
            Name = reader.GetString(0),
            Price = reader.GetDecimal(1),
            Description = reader.GetString(2),
            Image = reader.GetString(3)
        });
    }
```